# Why did SetWindowsHookEx with the WH_JOURNALRECORD hook type always return 0?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, hook, setwindowshookex

```
_ProcDlgMain PROC uses ebx edi esi hWnd,wMsg,wParam,lParam

    mov eax,wMsg
    .if eax ==  WM_CLOSE
        invoke  UnhookWindowsHookEx,hHook
        invoke  EndDialog,hWnd,NULL
    .elseif eax ==  WM_INITDIALOG
        push    hWnd
        pop hWinMain
        invoke AddDebugPrivilege
        invoke  SetWindowsHookEx,WH_JOURNALRECORD,addr HookProc,hInstance,NULL
        .if eax
            mov hHook,eax
        .else
            invoke  EndDialog,hWnd,NULL
        .endif
    .else
        mov eax,FALSE
        ret
    .endif
    mov eax,TRUE
    ret
_ProcDlgMain ENDP

start:  
    invoke  GetModuleHandle,NULL
    mov hInstance,eax
    invoke  DialogBoxParam,eax,DLG_MAIN,NULL,offset _ProcDlgMain,NULL
    invoke  ExitProcess,NULL
end start
```

Does anybody know why the `SetWindowsHookEx` function returns `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [`SetWindowsHookEx` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw):

> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. **To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).**

Which you are not doing.

However, it will likely report `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, because on Vista+ with UAC enabled, Journal hooks require the app to have a UAC manifest that specifies "uiaccess=true" permission:

[SetWindowsHookEx for WH_JOURNALRECORD fails under Vista/Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165666/)

However, seeing "uiaccess=true" carries additional restrictions, which your app is likely not satisfying:

- The executable must be digitally signed.
- The executable must reside in one of the following "secure" system folders (this can be disabled on Windows 10+ via a [policy setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations)):

  - `\Program Files\`, including subdirectories
  - `\Windows\system32\`
  - `\Program Files (x86)\`, including subdirectories for 64-bit versions of Windows

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had tried the way by using the makecert.exe and the signcode.exe to sign the "hook.exe", and then moved the "hook.exe" file to windows\system32, but it failed. I think maybe I haven't found a correct way to sing it.